# Check in and check out time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, time

[simple data of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOOXJ.png)

My table is:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [ID]
    ,[UserName]
    ,[CheckTime]
    ,[Checktype]
    ,[CheckinLocation]
    ,[lat]
    ,[lng]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CheckTime]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[CheckTime] ([UserName], [CheckTime], [Checktype],[CheckinLocation], [lat], [lng])
VALUES (<UserName, nchar(10),>
        ,<CheckTime, datetime,>
        ,<Checktype, nvarchar(50),>
        ,<CheckinLocation, nvarchar(50),>
        ,<lat, float,>
        ,<lng, float,>)
GO
```

Create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckTime]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [CheckTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Checktype] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CheckinLocation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lat] [float] NULL,
    [lng] [float] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CheckTime] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to select each distinct home holding the maximum value of datetime.

- max CheckTime as check out
- min CheckTime as check in

I need a result like this:

```
id | Username | check in          | check out
---+----------+-------------------+-------------------
1  |   10     | 2017-1-2 08:02:05 | 2017-1-2 10:02:05
1  |   12     | 2017-1-2 08:02:05 | 2017-1-2 10:02:05
1  |   12     | 2017-1-3 08:02:05 | 2017-1-3 10:02:05
1  |   10     | 2017-1-3 08:02:05 | 2017-1-3 10:02:05
```

I have tried:

Comment: Your insert statement do not contain data, please provide the data in insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
Select Username
  , Cast(CheckTime as Date) as CheckDate
  , min(CheckTime) as [check in]
  , max(CheckTime) as check out
From CheckInTable
Group by id, Username, Cast(CheckTime as Date)
```

Comment: id Username CheckDate check in check out
32 emad       2020-07-03 2020-07-03 12:36:29.000 2020-07-03 12:36:29.000
33 emad       2020-07-03 2020-07-03 12:36:35.000 2020-07-03 12:36:35.000 , it duplicate same username in date

Comment: @emadadel2008 I request you to include the sample data in your question. So, it will be easy to consume in the query. Better if you provide the data in SQL Server create and insert statement.

Comment: i edit the post install update cerate and simple data

Comment: @emadadel2008 Remove the Id column and check after running.